# Accessing Developer Stories over API

Tags: support, developer-story, api

I'm currently trying to get information about users on Stack Overflow. For this, I have to access the developer story of a user, and then read out the tags, which belong to different stations in the developer story.

Now, I was looking for a way to do this over the Stack Overflow API (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), but I don't seem to be able to find a way to access developer stories, or the information that is stored in one.

Is there simply no way to access the developer stories of a user over the API? Is it maybe just not yet implemented, since the feature is still new? Or is there another elegant way to access this information, without having to parse the HTML? Or are those tags maybe available over a different API function (maybe over `/users/{id}/tags`)?

Comment: Information specific to the Developer Story tab is not available through the API at this time. If you're looking for information about a user's participation in different tags, [that is available `/2.2/users/$ID/tags` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1114/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9YdnSClO\(), though it doesn't have the percentiles you see on dev story so it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: @JeremyBanks ok, that's what I expected. Thanks for the information. One followup question: Am I correct with my assumption, that I don't get the tags the user has entered in his story, if I access `/2.2/users/$ID/tags`?  And just for clarification, what do you mean with the percentiles?

Comment: [Related question on MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287211/148310).

Comment: No progress on that? It would be nice to be able to down/upload ones developer story to keep resumes in sync.

Answer (score 3):

To provide a short answer to this question, I refer Jeremy Banks comment on the original question:

There is **no API support** for developer stories in the Stack Overflow API as of Version 2.2.

It is possible to retrieve tags the user participated in over the default `/2.2/users/$ID/tags` API call, but those are only the tags, the user participated in, not the tags, the user has entered in his developer story.